# Confusion about solving quadratics $x^2-8x=5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I got into a little confusion, hopefully someone can clear it up for me.
So I'm solving $x^2-8x=5$ right, and here are my steps:

$$1: x^2-8x=5$$
$$2: x^2-8x+16=21$$
$$3: (x-4)^2=21$$
$$4: x-4=\pm\sqrt{21}$$
$$x=\pm\sqrt{21} +4$$

So I have a question, why is it plus or minus? I thought the square root is usually positive?

Comment: $ 4^2 = 25 $ is not true.

Comment: That's why I wrote it doesn't hold true.  Lets say its $x^2 = y$ then  $x = \sqrt{y}$ which I don't understand.

Comment: You are taking the square roots of equal numbers. If two numbers are equal, then their square roots are definitely equal as well.

Comment: I will also add link to the [original revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2597913/1). The [current revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2597913/4) no longer contains the second question. I think that since the answer which already respond to the second question were already given, editing that question out it not a good thing to do. (For other users reading this it might be unclear what those answers are actually responding to.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every positive number $n$ has two square roots: $\sqrt{n}$ and $-\sqrt{n}$. Both $4 + \sqrt{21}$ and $4 - \sqrt{21}$ are solutions to this equation. You can try plugging them in with your calculator to verify.

What you're thinking of here is that $\sqrt{n}$ refers only to the positive square root. If you want the other square root, you must specify $-\sqrt{n}$. This way, we never need to be confused when we see $\sqrt{n}$, even though $n$ has two roots.

As for your other question, it is not true that $\sqrt{x} + y = \sqrt{x + y}$, which is what you're observing here.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Well, I'm not saying that $\sqrt{x} + y = \sqrt{x + y}$. I'm saying that  $x^2 = y$ then  $x = \sqrt{y}$ which I don't understand.

Comment: On second look, I don't understand your second question at all. You seem to be starting by assuming a false equation ($4^2 = 25$) and concluding another false equation ($4 = 5$). I don't see the issue!

Comment: Okay just forget the $4^2 =25$ for a second. Is $x^2 = y$ then  $x = \sqrt{y}$ always true?

Comment: No. If $x^2 = y$, then $x = \sqrt{y}$ or $x = -\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: Okay so it's true but its positive and negative. Got it.

Comment: It's *almost* true. It's true up to a change of sign. It's just something you need to watch out for, like dividing by zero.

Comment: It's true up to a change of sign?

Comment: Well, I don't like saying "It's true, *but*...". If it's true, but..., then it's false. On the other hand, the word "false" has such a harsh connotation, and ignores how close the statement is to being true. So I say, it's true "up to a change of sign", meaning that the statement is either going to be true, or it will be false, but changing the sign of the result will make it true.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks Theo. :)

Comment: No problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There can be two square roots of every positive number: one positive and the other negative. For example, $ \sqrt 25 = ± 5$
 which is true as $ 5^2 = 25 $ and also, $ (-5)^2 = 25 $.

Yes, the square root is usually positive ( $ \sqrt x $ denotes the positive root of $x$ only), but square roots can be negative as well. The above example proved it already. Also, in the fourth step you should write,

$$ (x-4) = ± \sqrt 21 $$

Answer (score 1):

> First, why is it plus or minus?

Because the equation $\,x^2=b\,$ has two solutions $\,x = \,\pm \sqrt{b}\,$ when $\,b \gt 0\,$.

> I thought the square root is usually positive?

That's correct. The [real square root *function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Properties_and_uses) $\,\sqrt{\,\cdot\,}\,$ returns the *positive* solution, by definition.

> Second, and this really confuses me, we can see that in step 4 I removed the square from the factored side, what allows me to take the square root of the other side?

Suppose $\,a^2 = 21\,$, then that's equivalent to $\,a^2 - 21=0\,$, which using the algebraic identity $\,a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)\,$ with $\,b=\sqrt{21}\,$ is in turn equivalent to $\,(a - \sqrt{21})(a+\sqrt{21})=0\,$. Therefore one of the factors must be $\,0\,$, so either $\,a=\sqrt{21}\,$ or $\,a=-\sqrt{21}\,$, which is usually written as $\,a = \pm \sqrt{21}\,$. Your question is about the case where $\,a = x-4\,$.

Answer (score 1):

We have the equation
$$x^2 - 8x = 5$$
Add $16$ to both sides so we can factor the LHS in a nice way, so
\begin{align}
 x^2 - 8x + 16 &= 5 + 16 \\
 (x-4)^2 &= 21
\end{align}
Now take the square root on both sides (we can do this because both sides of the equation are positive terms)

$$ \sqrt{(x-4)^2} = \sqrt{21}$$

Notice that $x$ could be  a positive or negative number and still make the equation true,  we have to consider such cases, so

\begin{align}
x-4 &= \pm \sqrt{21} \\
x &= 4  \pm \sqrt{21}
\end{align}

will be the solutions to the quadratic equation.